# How to pass an HTML file from another location to jsPDF for PDF generation?

Tags: html, jspdf, html2canvas, angular12

I can pass the whole document or a section with an Id but i need to specify a file in another location. I´m using Angular 12.
I have the jspdf html2canvas function on a service, and on a document i need to pass it which html it needs to render.
Tried using HttpClient, fetch... hasn´t worked so far.

Comment: You can create an `iframe` element that points to the related page and then try to print the iframe.